# Virtual function emulated in C

Tags: c, function, virtual

I have the example of the code in C, which emulates the virtual function Shape_area().

There is one line of code which I don't understand: `return (*me->vptr->area)(me);`

Why do we use '*' before 'me'?

Could You explain to me that part, please?
Thanks

```
/*shape.h*/

struct ShapeVtbl; /* forward declaration */
typedef struct {
    struct ShapeVtbl const *vptr; /* <== Shape's Virtual Pointer */
    int16_t x; /* x-coordinate of Shape's position */
    int16_t y; /* y-coordinate of Shape's position */
} Shape;

/* Shape's virtual table */
struct ShapeVtbl {
    uint32_t (*area)(Shape const * const me);
};

/* Shape's operations (Shape's interface)... */
void Shape_ctor(Shape * const me, int16_t x, int16_t y);
void Shape_moveBy(Shape * const me, int16_t dx, int16_t dy);

uint32_t Shape_area(Shape const * const me) {
    return (*me->vptr->area)(me);
}
```

Comment: not every code you see on internet is good

Comment: @P__J__ This is the traditional way to invoke a function through a function pointer.  Later, the explicit dereference was made optional, but many people prefer to keep it since it's clearer and more consistent with the declarator.  There's certainly nothing wrong with doing so.

Answer (score 6):

If it's a function pointer, it's not required. It's the same with or without.

The idea is that it's a "pointer to a function" so you want to dereference the pointer to be able to use it as a function. But function names are effectively just pointers too and you don't need to dereference those as well, so they are equivalent.

`(*me->vptr->area)(me)` is equivalent to `(me->vptr->area)(me)` as is `printf("foo")` is equivalent to `(*printf)("foo")` (though you'll never write it this way).

You can keep it in or remove it, it doesn't really matter. Personally if it's specifically a pointer to a function and not a named function itself, I would leave it in to keep with the "dereference to use it" idea.

Comment: Truth is, the parenthesis around the pointer don't appear to be needed either.

Comment: True, though only if we left out the dereferencing `*`.

Answer (score 2):

The function Shape_area() is defined as:

```
uint32_t Shape_area(Shape const * const me) {
    return (*me->vptr->area)(me);
}
```

This means the function `Shape_area()` accepts a pointer to a struct of type Shape.

So in order to get to the actual function pointer for the virtual function the definitions for the various structs are as follows.

First struct is the actual data struct which contains the data along with the virtual function pointer.

```
typedef struct {
    struct ShapeVtbl const *vptr; /* <== Shape's Virtual Pointer */
    int16_t x; /* x-coordinate of Shape's position */
    int16_t y; /* y-coordinate of Shape's position */
} Shape;
```

There are two data items, `x` and `y`, along with a pointer to the virtual pointer which will contain the pointer to the actual function to be used.

That pointer to the virtual function is enclosed with a struct and is defined as:

```
struct ShapeVtbl {
    uint32_t (*area)(Shape const * const me);
};
```

So if we use one of these data structs it would be something like the following source code snippet.

```
uint32_t doVirt (Shape const * const me)
{
    // do things with the x and y data from variable me.
    // reference me->x and me->y to access those values.

    return 0;
}

struct ShapeVtbl myVirt = { doVirt };  // create a struct containing pointer to our function

Shape myShape;    // define our data structure

myShape.x = 32;          // set the x coordinate
myShape.y = 45;          // set the y coordinate
myShape.vptr = &myVirt;  // set the pointer to the virtual function pointer.

Shape_area (&myShape);   // call Shape_area with our struct.
```

The function `Shape_area()` will take the pointer to the `myShape` struct and then access the virtual function specified through the function pointer provided.

If we look at [operator precedence table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) we can see that `*me->vptr->area` is the same as `*(me->vptr->area)` or in other words the asterisk is being used to dereference the function pointer using standard pointer dereference syntax.

However with function pointers this syntax is not necessary though it can still be done. So `(*me->vptr->area)()` is the same as `(me->vptr->area) ()` is the same as `me->vptr->area()` due to the operator precedence rules.